Defining custom layer and custom loss based on outputs of all Layers
I am trying to implement Nueral Network for decoding noisy recived signal. Each layer of my neural network is like this:
Single Layer
My attempt:
class DetNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, K, N, L, v_size, hl_size, res_alpha=0.9, log_loss=True):
        super(DetNet, self).__init__()
        self.K = K
        self.N = N
        self.L = L
        self.v_size = v_size
        self.hl_size = hl_size
        self.res_alpha = res_alpha
        self.log_loss = log_loss

        self.layers_detnet = []
        for i in range(L):
            layer = DetNetLayer(K, v_size, hl_size, res_alpha, name=f'layer_{i}')
            self.layers_detnet.append(layer)

    def call(self, HY, HH, X, training=False):
        S = [tf.zeros_like(X)]
        V = [tf.zeros((tf.shape(HY)[0], self.v_size),dtype=tf.dtypes.as_dtype(HY.dtype))]
        losses = []
        bers = []

        for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers_detnet):
            Z = tf.concat([HY, S[-1], tf.linalg.matvec(HH, S[-1]), V[-1]], axis=-1)
            S_next, V_next = layer(Z, training=training)
            S.append(S_next)
            V.append(V_next)

            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(X - S[-1]), axis=-1) / tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(X - tf.squeeze(tf.linalg.solve(HH, tf.expand_dims(HY, 2)), axis=2)), axis=-1))
            if self.log_loss:
                loss *= tf.math.log(tf.cast(i + 1, tf.float32))
            losses.append(loss)

            ber = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.not_equal(X, tf.sign(S[-1])), tf.float32))
            bers.append(ber)

        total_loss = tf.add_n(losses)
        return total_loss, bers

class DetNetLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, K, v_size, hl_size, res_alpha, **kwargs):
        super(DetNetLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.K = K
        self.v_size = v_size
        self.hl_size = hl_size
        self.res_alpha = res_alpha

        self.W1 = self.add_weight(shape=(3 * K + v_size, hl_size), initializer='glorot_uniform', trainable=True)
        self.b1 = self.add_weight(shape=(hl_size,), initializer='zeros', trainable=True)
        self.W2 = self.add_weight(shape=(hl_size, K), initializer='glorot_uniform', trainable=True)
        self.b2 = self.add_weight(shape=(K,), initializer='zeros', trainable=True)
        self.t = self.add_weight(shape=(), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1), trainable=True)
        self.W3 = self.add_weight(shape=(hl_size, v_size), initializer='glorot_uniform', trainable=True)
        self.b3 = self.add_weight(shape=(v_size,), initializer='zeros', trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        Z = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.W1) + self.b1)
        S_next = self.piecewise_linear_soft_sign(tf.matmul(Z, self.W2) + self.b2, self.t)
        V_next = tf.matmul(Z, self.W3) + self.b3
        if training:
            return (1 - self.res_alpha) * S_next, (1 - self.res_alpha) * V_next
        else:
            return S_next, V_next


And my training loop is (I am using tf.GradientTape):
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    epoch_loss = 0
    for HY_, HH, X in train_dataset:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss, bers = detnet(HY_, HH, X, training=True)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, detnet.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, detnet.trainable_variables))
        epoch_loss += loss.numpy()
        temp.append(loss.numpy())
    epoch_loss /= (num_train_samples // batch_size)
    train_losses.append(epoch_loss)

    # Evaluate on validation set
    val_loss, _ = detnet(HY_val_, HH_val, X_val, training=True)
    val_losses.append(val_loss.numpy())
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}, Training Loss: {epoch_loss}, Validation Loss: {val_losses[-1]}")
    

Is there any issue in above? I am unable to get the right BERs as the paper, my loss function saturates as 1500, while I expect it to got till 500.
